# Spring JavaConfig JPA issue - " No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined"

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I'm in the process of converting XML based configuration for a Spring Java Web project to JavaConfig.

I'm using JPA. So I created an additional JavaConfig class with the necessary configuration. But the JPA configuration fails for some reason.

Here is my [web.xml][1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
       fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
       specified for component-scanning -->
<!--  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.my.contoso.spring.contosoJPA</param-value>
  </context-param>-->

  <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
           instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
           and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>com.my.contoso.spring.contosoConfig</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>

    <!--
        This Servlet mapping means that this Servlet will handle all incoming requests
     -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- for CORS -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- End for CORS -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<filter>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
         </init-param> 
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<!--    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/contosoDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>-->
</web-app>
```

Here is my primary [JavaConfig class][2]

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
//@ImportResource("contoso-jpa.xml") //Import any existing xml context files
@Import(contosoJPA.class)
//@EnableTransactionManagement //substitute for  <tx:annotation-driven/>
@ComponentScan({"com.my.contoso.webservices.rest", "com.my.contoso.services,com.my.contoso.dao"})
public class contosoConfig {

}
```

And Here's the JavaConfig class with [JPA config][3]

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories //(basePackages = { "com.my.contoso.domain" })
public class contosoJPA {


         @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
    //        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(H2).build();

            DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();


        try {
            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setUsername("root");
            ds.setPassword("");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contosodb");

        } catch (Exception e) {
    //        logger.error(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return ds;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
            lef.setPackagesToScan("com.my.contoso.domain");
            lef.setPersistenceUnitName("contosoPU");
            return lef;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    //        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new JpaTransactionManager();
        }   

}
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.lookupEntityManagerFactory(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:179)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
```

'entityManagerFactory' is declared in the [web.xml][1]. The error says that a bean with such name doesn't exist. But I did include it in the  [JPA config][3] file. So I'm guessing that the beans in the JPA javaConfig file are not getting picked up. Wondering where the configuration is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment out

```
<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
       fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
       specified for component-scanning -->
<!-- <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>com.uhsarp.billrive.spring.BillriveJPA</param-value>
 </context-param>-->
```

?

It seems to me like that root context should be loaded and made available to the whole application through the `ContextLoaderListener`. That `context-param` needs to be available so that the root context has a source from which to load bean definitions.

Comment: I have a total of 2 JavaConfig classes, The main context and the one for JPA. The main one is loaded later in the web.xml in the servlet declaration. The main config file then imports the JPA config file. Wouldn't this suffice? I also tried un-commenting it out and loaded the main context in its place but no dice. For some reason, the context files are just not getting picked up.

Comment: @user1324816 Edit your question and add the context classes/files that you have. We don't want to follow links. It'll be easier to see where something is missing.

Comment: Modified to include the sources directly. Thanks.

Comment: @user Please post the full stack trace, too.

Comment: Added the full stack trace. I did not previously add it as I did not see anything that stood out.

Comment: @user1324816 The `CORSFilter` is trying to load a bean from the root context. But the bean it needs is defined in the servlet context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Doesn't everything in the Root context gets shared by all the servlet contexts?

Comment: @user Right, but you aren't loading a root context, your loading a servlet context with a DispatcherServlet. The root context is loaded by a ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: Which bean are you referring to that you said is loaded from the root context? Also all of my Spring beans are made available in that context loaded by the Servlet. I'm missing something here

Comment: The beans are available in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` (aka as child context) they aren't available in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` (aka the ROOT context). The latter is empty, contains 0 beans. Filters can only access beans in the root context and not from child contexts (as there can be more then 1 child context, which one should it pick!).

Comment: @user1324816 As M. Deinum stated above, the `DispatcherServlet` loads a child context (servlet context) which is only available to itself. The `CORSFilter` tries to find beans in the root context, but you don't have one because your `ContextLoaderListener` doesn't have a `contextConfigLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

i would try to remove parameters and call bean methods manually:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.my.contoso.domain");
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("contosoPU");
        return lef;
    }
```

then
try to debug/sout if spring get to any method from this configuration class.

Maybe mixing web.xml configuration with java config is not the best idea? Did you consider to migrate it? :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by calling the bean methods manually? Thanks. Also can you help me understand the migration part from web.xml to compete javaconfig? I'm having a tough time finding the documentation on moving to JavaConfig. Thanks again!

Comment: those 2 lines - lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter()); you call here Bean methods manually, to be honest I have never used parameters which autowire beans from same Configuration class (maybe they work in the same way). About java config - I will put some example tomorrow, no time to search it now. Did you try to put some Syste.out.println to check if your configuration class is called?